# Hosting single project in different server

Tags: python, django

I've a django web application and it contains lots of app like (event, result, exam, ....).  Suppose in the future it become heavy application. Now my question is can split event app from project and host it somewhere else. like in different server and link back it to project. Here I need suggestion, if it is possible then how if not then is there any alternative way.

Comment: one server may access other server using REST API - it means you call HTTP requests from one server to other server.

Comment: this means I can't able to split already integrated app in the future, I have to develop another project and use rest api to call

Comment: what do you mean "it becomes heavy application"? why would you want to host the app on a different server? How does this help what problem?

Comment: I mean, suppose In future event app got lots of request,  In that case how to maintain. I think splitting event app from project and host somewhere else can solve problem.